# Oracle Apex integration using/from ASP.NET  C#; DB-Oracle

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm looking for a simple guide how to use Oracle Apex to show info from DB  integrating it with .NET using c#. So I hope you could share any tutorials about APEX & .NET integration, links exmaples, maybe a plan how would you connect these two technologies to show information in a apealing way to User.:
My plan:

1.Connect to Oracle db from .net

2.Use webservices(no idea how yet..., I understan how webservices work but...)

3.Integrate with Apex(???), than we could give Oracle DB schemas through .net/webservices and Apex could show information in the Browser

I'm looking for practical suggestions! explanation how to do this, tutorials, links, books, examples, links to examples...

Peace,
WiseMokn

p.s. any great, practical, with lots of examples, book about apex&c# would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the articles on working with [Oracle and Microsoft enterprise library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DAAB_On_ODPNet.aspx)

also this [tutorial from devstuff](http://devstuffs.wordpress.com/2010/02/04/using-enterprise-library-with-oracle-odp-net-2/)

see [Oracle Forum](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/products/index.html#FORUM) also

One [SO question regarding this is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652587/why-use-oracle-application-express-for-web-app)

Comment: Thx but the last link has no theory on practical usage or examples

Answer (score 0):

If you are only wanting apex for reporting, you can pass parameters in the apex URL to the apex report to do some basic things like filter.

I'm not very clear on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: GUIDE TO CONNECT .NET TO ORACLE APEX C# USING ORACLE DB @EMU