# What is the actual use of Oracle Application Express?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

What is the actual use of Oracle Application Express?
After viewing several tutorials and videos, I came across that it is to make applications for Oracle RDBMS.
If I am right, then is it possible to develop application without using Oracle Application Express?

Comment: "*is it possible to develop application without using Oracle Application Express*" - yes absolutely.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh you little rascal!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name technically correct - but IRL apex is The Only Way to build any application ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

waleed,
   Application Express is a rapid Web application development tool that lets you share data and create applications. Using only a Web browser and limited programming experience, you can develop and deploy applications that are fast and secure.

---

For Actual use look at [Why use Oracle Application Express for web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652587/why-use-oracle-application-express-for-web-app) 
Answer of your last question is yes you are right there are lots of development tool for develope Applications.

For worldwide use of Oracle Apex look at [Oracle Application Express Statitics](http://joelkallman.blogspot.in/2014/05/oracle-application-express-fast-like.html)

Comment: Thankyou very much. This very helpful for me to understand further concepts.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to develop a software which runs on web or cloud 24 hours rapidly apex is the way to go.  The backed for apex is always oracle.
Yes you can make application wihtout apex . .But all depends what type of application are you developing .A database intensive application then it requires a back end which can be oralce or sql server or mysql.
Or it can be a system generated application
Hope this info helps